# How to save pillow processed image in already existing Django object

Tags: django, django-models, python-imaging-library

I have created a object model as below

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class ImageModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    editedImg = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.image.delete()
        self.editedImg.delete()
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

And here is what i am trying to do in a function

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from EditorApp.forms import ImageForm
from EditorApp.models import ImageModel
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from PIL import Image

def edit_column(request):
    codArr = request.POST.getlist('codArr[]')
    imgs = ImageModel.objects.first()
    orgImage = ImageModel.objects.first().image
    orgImage = Image.open(orgImage)
    croppedImg = orgImage.crop((int(codArr[0]), int(codArr[1]), int(codArr[2]), int(codArr[3])))
    # croppedImg.show()
    # imgs.editedImg = croppedImg
    # imgs.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/editing/")
```

What i am trying to do is the codArr consists of coordinates of top(x, y) and bottom(x, y) in the array form(Which is not an issue and is tested(`croppedImg.show()` showed the desired cropped image) and handled and used to crop the image). Image crop is working fine. But what i am trying to do is to save the cropped image in `editedImg` of the model used above. The above commented one is what i tried but throw a error `AttributeError: _committed`

As i have not used any name for image in model as its not required.
Kindly help please, Would be very thankfull.

Comment: Use a context manager to open and save the image, then easily add the path to the image field in your DB; Take a look at Pillow's doc https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#create-thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

you should do it like this:

```
from io import BytesIO
from api.models import ProductPicture
from django.core import files

codArr = request.POST.getlist('codArr[]')
img_obj = ImageModel.objects.first()
orgImage = img_obj.image
orgImage = Image.open(orgImage)
croppedImg = orgImage.crop((int(codArr[0]), int(codArr[1]), int(codArr[2]), int(codArr[3])))
thumb_io = BytesIO()  # create a BytesIO object
croppedImg.save(thumb_io, 'png')
editedImg = files.File(thumb_io, name=file_name)
img_obj.editedImg = editedImg
img_obj.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and precious time. If possible kindly check below mine anser for further problem i faced. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's context manager to open the image and save it to the desired storage in that case I'm using the `images` dir.

Pillow will crop the image and image.save() will save it to the filesystem and after that, you can add it to Django's ImageField and save it into the DB.

> The context manager takes care of the file opening and closing, Pillow
> takes care of the image, and Django takes care of the DB.

```py
from PIL import Image

with Image.open(orgImage) as image:
    file_name = image.filename # Can be replaced by orgImage filename
    cropped_path = f"images/croped-{file_name}"
    # The crop method from the Image module takes four coordinates as input.
    # The right can also be represented as (left+width)
    # and lower can be represented as (upper+height).
    (left, upper, right, lower) = (20, 20, 100, 100)

    # Here the image "image" is cropped and assigned to new variable im_crop
    im_crop = image.crop((left, upper, right, lower))
    im_crop.save(cropped_path)
    imgs.editedImg = cropped_path
    imgs.save()
```

[Pillow's reference](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop)

Comment: Thank you for your reply and precious time. If possible kindly check below mine anser for further problem i faced. Thank you